# Get untruncated list of files that would be overwritten by checkout

Tags: git-checkout, git-reset

Suppose I want to check out branch X, and git says that many, many, many, VERY MANY files would be overwritten by checkout. So many in fact, that the list it writes out is truncated because it doesn't fit in some buffer.

Is there a way to get the complete list?

(**Important note to XY-problemers**: the X problem here, i.e. the reason why we are getting all these would-be-overwriten-by-checkout files in the first place, was conclusively and authoritatively determined to be **completely unsolvable and unmitigable**. Therefore the only way to avoid total defeat is to solve the Y problem instead: get a complete list of conflicting files and pass it to `rm`).

Answer (score -1):

First, you need to find out which files are staged for commit, but not committed yet, via

```
git status --porcelain
```

and then, let's see the already existent commits, specifically the files:

```
git diff X Y | grep '^\(+++\|---\)'
```

Comment: There are no "files staged for commit". I am not committing anything. I am on branch X and trying to check out branch Y, and this fails due to recurring permissions issues which are not preventable, not predictable, and cannot be safely `sudo chown -R`-ed in advance without looking case by case. This results in lots of files written to the tree that were added on branch Y, but HEAD stays on X because the checkout failed. We know we WILL be forced to deal with this regularly. Deleting those files is the correct solution (they're tracked anyway), we just need the full and clean list!

Comment: @SzczepanHołyszewski I have provided you two commands. The first is getting the unstaged changes. If that's empty, then proceed to the next one, which is showing the diff.